# Why do I keep getting mixed tabs and spaces in a Visual Studio 2010 C# code window?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have just been working on a C# file (Global.asax.cs) in a web application for the last hour or so, and I have been shown the prompt to "tabify" or whatever about four times.  Each time I choose to tabify and save the files, yet at some seemingly random point later on, I get prompted again.

I am using ReSharper, yet this doesn't happen when I code at home, also using ReSharper.  Only at work.

Comment: Is your tab indent setting set such that the spaces can actually be fully converted to tabs?

Comment: I also get this on one of my files now.  I've got it one to two times each hour today.  Even before the file was added to source control.

Comment: @LostHobbit It matters because an annoying dialogue keeps popping up and interrupting my flow.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Are you using the Productivity Power Tools VS 2010 extension?  If so, go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> and choose `Productivity Power Tools`.  Here you can turn off the option to `Fix Mixed Tabs`. This will turn off this warning.

[Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)

[Power Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)

[Power Tools for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)

[Power Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d)

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the warning and get rid of the mixed tabs and spaces instead.

Comment: @ProfK would the random point that you get prompted again also happen to be after someone else checks in changes to this file (if you're using source control)?  Maybe you and someone else have tab spaces defined differently in VS.

Comment: Hard to see how this is productive.  Turn off tabs with Tools + Options, Text Editor.  They were used in the previous century to save bytes.

Comment: @Hans, the productivity of using tabs is not at all relevant here.

Comment: The productivity of tabs has been well discussed and there is more merit to tabs than simply data size. Tabs have configurable widths for people with different indentation preferences working on the same project. If everyone configured their VS to use different numbers of spaces instead of tabs the code would become a mess, but if everyone uses tabs and configures the tab width to their visual preference then the code stays clean and everyone gets their cake and eats it too. What, again, is the advantage of using spaces?

Comment: Thank You! This has been driving me crazy for about a month now.

Comment: This solution works with Visual Studio 2013 as well.

Comment: Justin Saraceno is right! It's the "Productivity Power Tools VS 2010"!!!

The annoying thing is, that the question sometimes comes up even if you have set the Editor to insert spaces instead of Tabs.

Comment: @TheXenocide More granular alignment options is one. The auto-width of tabs can be very nice (I'm pro-tab myself,) but for doing things like aligning assignments or declaration, you can end up adding more space than you want just get tabs to line up. Now if only VS would attempt to backspace through a tab's worth of spaces at once...

Comment: @JohnNeuhaus Tabs are not for alignment, but for indentation _only_ (and the only reasonable option for that, too). But for alignment, always use spaces. Tabs should never appear to the right of a letter.

Comment: Happy to be able to turn this "feature" off!  It's particularly annoying when trying to debug something & stepping into the module triggers this dialog to show up!

Comment: @TheXenocide Spaces are required if you are going to align code at positions within a line (not at the beginning). If you stop trying to do that ridiculous thing, though, then tabs work *much better*. I hate spaces. I hate pressing backspace and only one space gets deleted. I hate seeing misaligned (on the left side) code. I hate seeing a line indented 20 spaces from the previous line to "line up". So I'm with you, but you have to at least cover the "mixed tabs and spaces" that is forced on you with the alignment thing.

Answer (score 66):

The mixed tabs and spaces might come from your visual studio text editor setting. You can decide if you want visual studio to insert spaces or tabs here:

Tools/Options/ -> Text Editor/All Languages/Tabs, select the "Keep Tabs" option.

Comment: This is really the right answer to the question asked and the result @ProfK wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

Choose the "Untabify" option since VS defaults to spaces, not tabs. If you choose "Tabify" the next time you add a line, VS will use spaces and you'll see the prompt over and over.

Answer (score 10):

`Resharper` uses seperate **tab/space** settings to visual studio.  In the `Resharper` options, check "General Formatter Style -> How to align when tabs are used for indents".  This setting is used when `resharper` is formatting code (such as refactoring etc) and defaults to "User Spaces".

Also, in "**Edit -> Advanced**" menu, there is a "View Whitespace" option (Ctrl + E, S) which may be useful!

Comment: Good option (the View Whitespace one)! +1